# How to store in LocalStorage in this case?

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

In simple terms, I want the site to save when creating new rectangles or adding images via drag and drop. I'm relatively inexperienced in this area and the youtube videos I've watched haven't helped me much. Does it make sense to work with JSON files here or is it sufficient to save only in the browser?

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cop Or Drop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/miniLogo.svg">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="justify-content-space-between navbar navigation">
                <div class="placeholder ms-5">
                    <p>Log-In</p>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-brand">
                    <img src="img/navLogo.svg" width="150px" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="login me-5">
                    <button class="open-button">Log-In</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
    <div id="login-field" class="login-field">
        <button class="close-button"><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></button>
        <form class="form" id="login">
            <h1 class="form__title">Log-In</h1>
            <div id="errormsg" class="form__message form__message_error">Incorrect Password!</div>
            <div class="form__input-group">
                <input id="email" type="text" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="E-Mail">
            </div>
            <div class="form__input-group">
                <input id="password" type="text" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Password">
                <div class="form__input-error-message"></div>
            </div>
            <button id="submit-button" class="form__button" type="submit">Continue</button>
        </form>
</div>
</div>
<button id="myButton"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i></button>
<script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ca61e08eab.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```css
h1{
    color: white !important;
    font-size: 50px;
    }
    
    .login button{
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    }
    .navigation{
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255,255,255, 0.1), rgba(255,255,255,0));
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255, 0.18);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.37);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    }
    
    .placeholder{
    font-size: 15px !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
    }
    
    body{
    background-image: url(img/background.svg) !important;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    --color-primary: #009579;
    --color-primary-dark: #007f67;
    --color-secondary: #252c6a;
    --color-error: #cc3333;
    --color-success: #4bb544;
    }
    
    .login-field{
    text-align: center;
    height: 400px;
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 1rem;
    padding: 2rem;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(50%);
    display: none;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255,255,255, 0.1), rgba(255,255,255,0));
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255, 0.18);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.37);
    z-index: 5;
    }
    
    .close-button{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    right:3%;
    top: 3%;
    }
    
    .close-button:active{
    color: var(--color-error);
    transform: scale(0.90);
    }
    
    .container{
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    }
    
    .form__input-group{
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
    
    .form__input{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0.75rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    border: 4px solid #eeeeee;
    transition: border-color 0.2s, background 0.2s;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    }
    
    .form__input:focus{
    border-color: var(--color-primary);
    background: #ffffff;
    }
    
    .form__button{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    transition: background 0.2s;
    }
    
    .form__button:hover{
    background-color: var(--color-primary-dark);
    }
    
    .form__message{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
    
    .form__message_error{
    color: var(--color-error);
    font-family:monospace;
    visibility: hidden;
    }
    
    .form__message_success {
    color: var(--color-success);
    }
        
    .form__input-error-message,
    .form__input--error {
    color: var(--color-error);
    border-color: var(--color-error);
    }
        
    .form__button:active {
    transform: scale(0.98);
    }
        
    #myButton {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 3%;
    right: 3%;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    border-radius: 500px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    }

    .hover{
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
        border: 1px dashed #fff !important;
    }

    .valid{
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4bb544;
        border: 1px solid green;
    }

    .invalid{
        color: #fff;
        background-color: red;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
        
    .inactive,
    .active {
    width: 60% !important;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255,255,255, 0.1), rgba(255,255,255,0));
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255, 0.18);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.37);
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    height: 150px !important;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    transition: height ease-in-out 0.5s, width ease-in-out 0.5s, border-radius ease-in-out 0.5s;
    }

    
        
    .active {
    width: 70% !important;
    border-radius: 40px;
    height: 400px !important;
    }

    .closeRectangleInactive,
    .closeRectangleActive {
        color: white;
        position: relative;
        align-self: flex-start;
        margin-left: 10px;
        font-size: 30px;
        transition: margin-left ease-in-out 0.5s, margin-top ease-in-out 0.5s, font-size ease-in-out 0.5s;
    }
    .closeRectangleActive:active{
        color: var(--color-error);
        transform: scale(0.90);
        }
    .closeRectangleInactive:active{
            color: var(--color-error);
            transform: scale(0.90);
            }
    .closeRectangleActive{
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        font-size:50px;
    }
    .field{
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        top: 40px;
        left: 340px;
        border: 1px dashed white;
        margin-right: 3%;
        margin-top: 1.5%;
        margin-bottom: 1.5%;
        transition: width ease-in-out 0.5s, height ease-in-out 0.5s;
        
    }
    .activeField{
        width: 240px;
        height: 240px;
        top: 40px;
        left: 340px;
        border: 1px dashed white;
        margin-right: 3%;
        margin-top: 1.5%;
        margin-bottom: 1.5%;
        transition: width ease-in-out 0.5s, height ease-in-out 0.5s;
    }


        
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    }
        
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #888;
    }
```

JS:

```
function init() {
let loginButton = document.querySelector(".open-button");
let closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");
let container = document.querySelector(".login-field");
loginButton.addEventListener("click", openLogin);
closeButton.addEventListener("click", closeLogin);
let button = document.getElementById("myButton");
button.addEventListener("click", createRectangle);



function openLogin() {
  container.style.display = "inline";
}
function closeLogin() {
  container.style.display = "none";
}
}

var activeRectangle;
var activeField;
var rectangleId = 0;
var fieldId = 0;

// create a new rectangle
function createRectangle() {
  var rectangle = document.createElement("div");
  rectangle.className = "inactive";
  rectangle.id = `rectangle-${rectangleId}`;
  console.log(rectangle.id)
  var field = document.createElement("div");
  field.className = "field";
  field.id = `field-${fieldId}`;
  
  rectangle.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (activeRectangle) {
      activeRectangle.classList.remove("active");
      activeRectangle.closeRectangle.classList.remove("closeRectangleActive");
      activeRectangle.closeRectangle.classList.add("closeRectangleInactive");
      activeRectangle.classList.add("inactive");
      if (activeRectangle.classList.contains("inactive")) {
        activeField.classList.add("field");
        activeField.classList.remove("activeField");
      }
    }

    rectangle.classList.remove("inactive");
    rectangle.closeRectangle.classList.remove("closeRectangleInactive");
    rectangle.classList.add("active");
    rectangle.closeRectangle.classList.add("closeRectangleActive");
    if (!rectangle.classList.contains("inactive")) {
      field.classList.add("activeField");
      field.classList.remove("field");
      activeField = field;
    }
    
    activeRectangle = rectangle;


  });
  console.log(rectangle.className);
  document.body.appendChild(rectangle);

  
  var icon = '<i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>';
  rectangle.closeRectangle = document.createElement("div");
  rectangle.closeRectangle.className = "closeRectangleInactive";
  rectangle.closeRectangle.id = `close-button-${rectangleId}`;
  console.log(rectangle.id)
  rectangle.closeRectangle.innerHTML = icon;
    rectangle.closeRectangle.addEventListener("click", function() {
      rectangle.remove();
        console.log(rectangle.id)
      
      });

  rectangleId++;
  fieldId++;
  rectangle.appendChild(rectangle.closeRectangle);



  rectangle.appendChild(field);
  document.body.appendChild(rectangle);


// Add event listeners to change the border color when a file is dragged over or out of the field
field.addEventListener("dragover", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  field.style.border = "2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)";
  field.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)";
});
field.addEventListener("dragleave", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  field.style.border = "1px solid black";
});



// Add event listener to open file explorer when field is clicked
field.addEventListener("click", event => {
  const input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "file";
  input.addEventListener("change", event => {
    const file = input.files[0];
    const fileType = file.type.split("/")[1];
    if (fileType === "png" || fileType === "jpg" || fileType === "jpeg") {
        // Create an image element
        const img = new Image();
        // Set the image source to the file data
        img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        // Set the width and height of the image to match the field
        img.style.width = "100%";
        img.style.height = "100%";
        // Remove any existing image from the field
        while (field.firstChild) {
          field.removeChild(field.firstChild);
        }
        // Append the new image to the field
        field.appendChild(img);
        field.style.border = "1px solid green";
        field.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        console.log("File uploaded");
    } else {
        field.style.border = "1px solid red";
        field.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        console.log("Wrong file format");
    }
  });
  input.click();
});

}

init();
```

Comment: But what kind of details?

Comment: Probably what is needed from you is what you mean by "does it make sense" and "sufficient". What do you mean in objective terms? In other words, what are the criteria you _need_ to meet here for your business case/use case?